# What is the equivalence class of this equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, equivalence-relations, congruences

Note: This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications [7th ed, prob 26 pg 645].

Problem:
What is the equivalence class of this equivalence relation? 
Relation {(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3)}
on the set {0, 1, 2, 3}.

This is my book's definition of an equivalence class of a.

[image]

And This is an example that the book used to demonstrate the concept of an equivalence class
[image]

The definition and example combination made sense to me. Finding the equivalence class of 0 of modulo 4 meant all the elements related to 0 of the set congruence modulo 4, meaning all elements that have property $\equiv$ 0 mod(4). 
How would you apply the idea to a whole relation(set)? The definition implied that you can only have an equivalence class of an element, not a set.

Comment: Yes, an equivalence class is the equivalence class of an element. Here there are two equivalence classes, $\{0,1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$.

Comment: What is {3} the equivalence class of? And same of {0, 1, 2}?

Comment: $\{3\}$ is the equivalence class of $3$. The other one is the equivalence class of $0$. It is also the equivalence class of $1$. It is also the equivalence class of $2$. Think of an equivalence class as a family. The numbers $0,1,2$ are in the same family. But $3$ is solitary, it is not related to anybody except himself.

Comment: Is your problem correct? don't you have forget $(2,1)$ in the relation definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André Nicolas is correct in the comments, but I would like to try to explain it a bit slower. As your definition says, the equivalence class of an element $a$ is *all* the elements that are related to $a$ through a given equivalence relation $R$.

So let's take your example. We have the set $X = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and the following equivalence relation on the set:
$$R = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 3)\}.$$
Notice that, as Emilio Novati pointed out in the comments, the relation you posted in your question is in fact *not* an equivalence relation, since $(1,2) \in R$, but $(2,1) \notin R$, so it is not symmetric. Hence I have added the element $(2,1)$ to the relation.

Now, what is the equivalence class of $0$? Well, $0$ is related to $1$ through $(0,1) \in R$, it is related to itself (this will always be the case since it is an equivalence relation, and hence reflexive) through $(0,0) \in R$, it is related to $2$ through $(0,2) \in R$, but it is not related to $3$ through any element in $R$. So the equivalence class of $0$ is
$$[0] = \{0,1,2\}.$$
Similarly, since we now know that $1 \in [0]$, we must have $[1] = [0]$ and by the same logic we also get $[2] = [0]$.

I hope that now it should also be obvious that $[3] = \{3\}$.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes it more clear. Why theorem did you use to state that "we now know that $1 \in [0]$, we must have $[1] = [0]$"?

Comment: @committedandroider It's not really any particular theorem. It's just that since we know that $1$ is related to $0$, $0$ must also be related to $1$ (by symmetry), and it must be related to every other element in the class (by transitivity), so if an element $x$ is in another element $y$'s equivalence class, then $[x] = [y]$. In fact, this is the whole idea behind equivalence classes and why they are interesting!